# How can I get a document with an ID that matches an ID in another collection?

Tags: get, flutter-futurebuilder

Thank you so much to anyone who can help me. I am coming back to Flutter after a long break and attempting to follow an existing code base to solve my query, but it's not working.

I have two collections:
businessProfiles - contain the details of the business
socialValue - contains the socialValue scores for each of the businessProfiles

I am trying to get a document with the field businessProfileID in each document in the socialValue collection where the businessProfileID in the passed object called BusinessProfile matches from the app.

I apologise I am a novice, but have been trying at this for hours.

The result I get is null check operator on a null value

I created this in the firestore service file

```
final socialValueRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('socialValue').withConverter<SocialValue>(fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => SocialValue.fromDocument(snapshots.data()as Map<String,dynamic>), toFirestore: (doc, _) => doc.toJson());


Future<DocumentSnapshot<SocialValue>> getMySocialValueForBusProfile(String socialValueID) async => await socialValueRef.doc(socialValueID).get();
```

I created this as Modal (example)

```
class SocialValue {
  String? businessProfileID;
  num? un1poverty;
  num? un2hunger;
  num? un3wellbeing;

SocialValue({
    this.businessProfileID,
    this.un1poverty,
    this.un2hunger,

factory SocialValue.fromDocument(Map<String, dynamic> doc) {
    return SocialValue(
      businessProfileID: doc['businessProfileID'] ?? '',
      un1poverty: doc['un1poverty'] ?? '',
      un2hunger: doc['un1poverty'] ?? '',

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'businessProfileID':businessProfileID,
      'un1poverty':un1poverty,
      'un2hunger':un2hunger,
```

I created this as screen in flutter (test)

```
class GetSampleDocument extends StatelessWidget {
  final SocialValue? socialValue;
  final BusinessProfile? businessProfile;

  GetSampleDocument({this.businessProfile, this.socialValue});

  final firestoreService = Get.find<FirestoreService>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Image.asset('assets/images/applogo.png', height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 15), backgroundColor: primaryColor),
      body:
      FutureBuilder(
          future: firestoreService.getMySocialValueForBusProfile(socialValue!.businessProfileID!),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<SocialValue>> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return LoadingData();
            else {
              SocialValue socialValue = snapshot.data!.data() as SocialValue;
              return
                Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Heading(title: 'SOCIAL VALUE PROFILE', textScaleFactor: 1.75),


          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: appBackground,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 15),

                    Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(padding),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text('Social Value', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal.shade400, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            SizedBox(height: 15),
                            Text(socialValue.un1poverty!.toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

]
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
    }),
      );
  }
}
```

The result is null check operator used on a null value

Comment: Have you tried checking snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done before working with your snapshot data?